# If f=u+iv and u and v satify the Cauchy-Riemann equations does that imply that f is analytic? or do we need more conditions

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-riemann-equations

If  f=u+iv and u and v satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations does that imply that f is analytic? or do we need more conditions

Comment: If you add the condition that $f$ is real Frechet differentiable, then you can conclude from the Cauchy Riemann equations that $f$ is complex Frechet differentiable, and then by complex analysis that $f$ is analytic.

Answer (score 1):

If $u$ and $v$ are real differentiable functions,  then holomorphicity of $f$ is equivalent to satisfaction of the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

But $f$ is holomorphic if and only if analytic.

[Here's](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations#Interpretation_and_reformulation) a discussion.